# Make iframe float on right of vertical-alignment

Tags: html, css, iframe

I want to add an iframe to the  right of the vertical-alignment

http://s13.postimg.org/s5f54mux3/Screen_Shot_2015_07_30_at_4_45_06_PM.png

The code to it is:

```
                    <div style='margin-left:10px;'>
                        <img src='/' class='circular' style='float:left;vertical-align:middle;'>
                    </div>
                </span>
                <span class='txt'>
                    <span class='user-info'> 
                        Text
                    </span>
                    <br>
                <span class='user-time'>
                    12 Minutes Ago   
                </span> 
            </span>
        </span> 
    </span>
</div>
```

How do you add an iframe to float on the right of the vertical-alignment, like so...

http://s30.postimg.org/5qfa3x8o1/Screen_Shot_2015_07_30_at_4_45_06_PM.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution would be to add a `float:right` and position it as the last element of the `span` that contains the user information.

I think I placed it correctly below but the code you posted is missing the top half, making it kind of difficult to guess what is what..

```
                <div style='margin-left:10px;'>
                    <img src='/' class='circular' style='float:left;vertical-align:middle;'>
                </div>
            </span>
            <span class='txt'>
                <span class='user-info'> 
                    Text
                </span>
                <br>
                <span class='user-time'>
                12 Minutes Ago   
                </span> 
            </span>
            <iframe style:'float:right;'></iframe>
        </span> 
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: it works, but how do you align it with the image (on the left) just as the words are.

Comment: It would be wildly easier to help you with this if you posted a JSFiddle or something along those lines, but in a general sense the easiest way to achieve vertical centering for a block element with a fixed height parent is to set the top and bottom margins to ((height-of-parent) - (height-of-iframe))/2. or to put it more simple make the top and bottom margins of the iframe equal to half of the difference in height between the iframe and the parent

Answer (score 0):

To put an element on the right, you can either use `float: right` or absolute positioning. Personally I would use absolute positioning. Here is a solution:

```
#theIframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Also make sure the containing element is `position: relative` (or any other position except the default "static".)

Comment: Where would I put the iframe? Can you please put the alterations in the code I provided.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reluctant to butt in where a solution seems to have been reached but I'm wondering why one wouldn't use Flexbox. I understand that it's not supported in IE9- but the data at *Can I Use* suggests that this is a negligible concern and that cross-browser support is wide. [Can I Use Flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) (*Note:* review both the "Current Aligned" and "Useage Relative" data.)

With that in mind, would you consider something along the lines of the following.

//HTML

```
                <div style='margin-left:10px;'>
                <img src='/' class='circular' style='float:left;vertical-align:middle;'>
            </div>
        </span>
        <div id="Flex-Container">
          <span class='txt'>
            <span class='user-info'> 
              Text
            </span>
            <br>
            <span class='user-time'>
              12 Minutes Ago   
            </span> 
          </span>
          <div id="Responsive-Iframe-Container">...</div>
        </div>
      </span> 
    </span>
  </div>
```

//CSS

```
#Flex-Container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
#Responsive-Iframe-Container {
  width: 45%;
}
```

The HTML and CSS for the markup inside #Responsive-Iframe-Container can be found in the Pen [Responsive Iframe - Flexbox](http://codepen.io/alxfyv/pen/mJaEZw?editors=110).

Of course, instead of using #Responsive-Iframe-Container, one could simply substitute `<iframe src="#"></iframe>` styled as desired.

I am a beginner autodidact in HTML and CSS, so if there is something wrong with the suggested code, please forgive me and please let me know what it is.